# vertical lines on screen(main cause might be youtube)

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, graphics-card, youtube

The issue is as follows:

I am on a 2 screen setup, most of the time on my system it works fine, with gaming, programming and 3d modeling.

When using youtube, the screen starts to glitch and display horizontal lines, i used to fix this by just rebooting, but later i have found out that if i closed the browser using alt-f4 the screen would recover, reopening youtube clip would cause the glitch again.

The glitch only occurs on the main screen, even if the clip is on my second screen.

My GPU is a 7970 card, running the 13.1 catalyst driver.

Comment: the 13.1 driver is very old. Try the 13.9: http://support.amd.com/us/kbarticles/Pages/AMDCatalyst13-9WINReleaseNotes.aspx, http://sites.amd.com/US/GAME/DOWNLOADS/Pages/radeon_win8-32.aspx, http://sites.amd.com/US/GAME/DOWNLOADS/Pages/radeon_win8-64.aspx

Comment: i know its the old one, but 13.9 makes some of my games crash after login, ill try the beta one see if that might help.

Comment: ok, try the 13.10: http://support.amd.com/us/kbarticles/Pages/AMDCatalyst13-10WINBetaDriver.aspx

Comment: tried it, back to game crashing again, i'm going to go down the list of other versions.